# psql extremely expanded display of table on command line

Tags: psql

I have a table that should be occupying much less space on psql command line, for some reason the format is being displayed very weirdly. Please have a look at this picture, it describes the problem better than any words I may write here.

[image]

As you may see some columns names are overlapping and the table is just ugly. If I expand the display you can see how the table is structured .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psql` does not add extra spaces to the output.

The problem must be that you have lots of training spaces at least in some of the data. `psql` will align the output with the widest column in the result set.

One possibility how that can happen is if you define columns with a type like `char(100)`, which will pad the value with spaces. It is a good idea to avoid the `char` data type.

Comment: I did exactly that. thanks